# Unable to parse the format string error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

My code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    cellText = @"Crysis 3 - 'The Nanosuit' Gameplay Trailer";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:cellText];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

And after build i have error

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "Crysis 3 - 'The Nanosuit' Gameplay Traile"'**

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing some DB value text to predicate with format.  See [NSPredicate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html).  It requires a string in a very structured format:

It's going to be something like:  `@"gameName like Crysis 3"`